# How to execute custom php on click button in order page list on woo-commerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

On the orders page in woo-commerce I added a button in the actions row, by click this button i want to make curl call to a web service, the code work well when I hook so_payment_complete function, but my goal now would be to make the call by clicking the button i added on orders page. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript code for make an ajax request to your PHP function through wordpress hook wp_ajax and wp_ajax_nopriv.

This is and example

JavaScript code:

```
$( "#button" ).on( "click", function(e) {
 e.preventDefault();
 $n.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>',
        data: YOUR DATA,
        async:true,
        success: function(msg){
        }
    });  
});
```

PHP code:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_action', 'FUNCTION_NAME' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_action', 'FUNCTION_NAME' );

function FUNCTION_NAME() {
    //YOUR CURL
}
```

Let me know.